# Windows RSAT Features On Demand offline installation through DISM not working

Tags: windows, powershell, cab, dism

Afternoon,
I am currently trying to install RSAT DNS Tools and Volume Activation Tools through DISM using PowerShell on a computer without internet. My environment is widely off the internet and thus not able to do this the normal way. I have the cab files for both downloaded off Microsoft VLSC, of those features but I get an error of: `Add-Windows Capability: The source files could not be found.`

My code used is"

`Add-WindowsCapability -online -name rsat.dns.tools~~~~0.0.1.0 -limitaccess -source C:\Source\BuildSource\Laptop\02-AdminCenter\RSATTools\`

I've also set the source path to the overarching CAB file as well (`C:\Source\BuildSource\Laptop\02-AdminCenter\RSATTools\Microsoft-Windows-DNS-Tools-FoD-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~en-US~.cab` and get the same error. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve it by mounting the original iso and not going through the specific cab files